# Why is Banshee crashing on launch in 10.04.2?

Tags: 10.04, banshee

I have downgraded to Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS for stability and I just installed Banshee through the software center. I don't have any Banshee plugins installed. When I try to open Banshee I just get this error:

```
An unhandled exception was thrown: Could not read add-in description

  at Mono.Addins.Addin.get_Description () [0x00000] 
  at Mono.Addins.AddinSessionService.CheckHostAssembly (System.Reflection.Assembly asm) [0x00000] 
  at Mono.Addins.AddinSessionService.ActivateRoots () [0x00000] 
  at Mono.Addins.AddinSessionService.Initialize () [0x00000] 
  at Mono.Addins.AddinManager.Initialize (System.String configDir) [0x00000] 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.ServiceManager.InitializeAddins () [0x00000] 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.ServiceManager.DefaultInitialize () [0x00000] 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.Application.Initialize () [0x00000] 
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Initialize (Boolean registerCommonServices) [0x00000] 
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient..ctor (Boolean initializeDefault, System.String defaultIconName) [0x00000] 
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient..ctor () [0x00000] 
  at Nereid.Client..ctor () [0x00000] 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] 
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] 
  at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic) [0x00000] 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] 
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Startup () [0x00000] 
  at Hyena.Gui.CleanRoomStartup.Startup (Hyena.Gui.StartupInvocationHandler startup) [0x00000] 

.NET Version: 2.0.50727.1433
OS Version: Unix 2.6.32.31

Assembly Version Information:

System.Xml (2.0.0.0)
System.Core (3.5.0.0)
gdk-sharp (2.12.0.0)
Mono.Addins (0.4.0.0)
atk-sharp (2.12.0.0)
Hyena.Gui (1.6.0.0)
gtk-sharp (2.12.0.0)
Banshee.Core (1.6.0.0)
Banshee.ThickClient (1.6.0.0)
Nereid (1.6.0.0)
NDesk.DBus.Proxies (0.0.0.0)
Mono.Posix (2.0.0.0)
System (2.0.0.0)
Hyena (1.6.0.0)
NDesk.DBus (1.0.0.0)
glib-sharp (2.12.0.0)
Banshee.Services (1.6.0.0)
Banshee (1.6.0.0)
mscorlib (2.0.0.0)

Platform Information: Linux 2.6.32-31-generic-pae i686 unknown GNU/Linux

Disribution Information:

[/etc/lsb-release]
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS"

[/etc/debian_version]
squeeze/sid
```

Here is the terminal output. Immediately after this, a dialog box pops up giving me the same error as I pasted above.

```
thomas@thomas-m15x:~$ banshee
[Info  21:02:07.481] Running Banshee 1.6.1: [Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (linux-gnu, i486) @ 2010-06-18 09:51:55 UTC]
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not read add-in description
  at Mono.Addins.Addin.get_Description () [0x00000] 
  at Mono.Addins.AddinSessionService.CheckHostAssembly (System.Reflection.Assembly asm) [0x00000] 
  at Mono.Addins.AddinSessionService.ActivateRoots () [0x00000] 
  at Mono.Addins.AddinSessionService.Initialize () [0x00000] 
  at Mono.Addins.AddinManager.Initialize (System.String configDir) [0x00000] 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.ServiceManager.InitializeAddins () [0x00000] 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.ServiceManager.DefaultInitialize () [0x00000] 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.Application.Initialize () [0x00000] 
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Initialize (Boolean registerCommonServices) [0x00000] 
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient..ctor (Boolean initializeDefault, System.String defaultIconName) [0x00000] 
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient..ctor () [0x00000] 
  at Nereid.Client..ctor () [0x00000] 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] 
  at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic) [0x00000] 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] 
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Startup () [0x00000] 
  at Hyena.Gui.CleanRoomStartup.Startup (Hyena.Gui.StartupInvocationHandler startup) [0x00000]
```

I have no idea why it's doing this. "Could not read add-in description." If it's referring to third-party extensions, then once again, I don't have any installed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by deleting the directory `~/.config/banshee-1/addin-db-001`. It works just fine now.